# How to debug using RTSM simulator in eclipse (for DS-5) for FreeRTOS?

Tags: eclipse-cdt, freertos, ds-5

I am new to FreeRTOS and RTSM simulator. I loaded the code of FreeRTOS and am trying to use the RTSM simulator (simulates ARM Cortex A9). When I change to DS-5 debug perspective and press Debug from Debug Configurations, the simulator seems to be running. The problem I am facing is that I am not able to step through my source code (for debugging). I put a break point in the first statement in main, and the control doesn't seem to be reaching there. (I am able to step through the assembly language code produced after compilation, but that is not what I need).

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Can you break it manually once it's been running for a moment and see how far it's ended up? Maybe it's spinning somewhere and never reaches main.